# Why do we use left feet to enter washroom?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, hadith-interpretation, sunnah

Did we have washrooms/toilets 1400 years ago in Arabia?

If not, how is this sunnah applicable for ***open air defecation***?

Comment: Any references to suggest that it's Sunnah?

Comment: The elders usually say it to be. Tbh I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular evidence for this sunnah excatly!
but scholars agree that we should enter the bathroom by left foot, and the 
there're two evidences for this:

1. there's a main rule that say: we should use the right as general for all good things, and use left for other.

> قَالَ حَدَّثَتْنِي حَفْصَةُ، زَوْجُ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ يَجْعَلُ يَمِينَهُ
>   لِطَعَامِهِ وَشَرَابِهِ وَثِيَابِهِ وَيَجْعَلُ شِمَالَهُ لِمَا سِوَى
>   ذَلِكَ ‏.‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) used his right hand for taking his food and drink and
>   used his left hand for other purposes.

2. by [Qiyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiyas), so from the sunnah using right foot to entering the mosque and left one to get out of it, so it's a reverse qiyas.

Comment: For this argumentation you may need to give a reference for entering the mosque with the right foort ;)